# how to fix 'Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined ' when saving a user

Tags: node.js, promise, model, try-catch, typeerror

There are a user model and the app.js,

in app.js we have a catch for the **user.save()** that throws the error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined
```

user model :

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 3        
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 5
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model( 'users', UserSchema )
```

app.js file :

```
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

const bcrypt = require( 'bcryptjs')
const User = require('./models/User')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))



app.listen( 4111, () => {
    console.log( 'listening on 4111 ...' )
})

mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/login', () => {
    console.log( 'Connected ! ')
})

app.post('/register', ( req, res ) => {
    let newUser = new User()
    newUser.email = req.body.email || 'gmail'
    newUser.password = req.body.password || 1234
    // res.send( newUser )
    bcrypt.genSalt( 10,  salt => {
        bcrypt.hash( req.body.password, salt, ( err, hash ) => {
            if( err ) return err 
            newUser.password = hash
            newUser.save().then( savedUser => {
                res.send( 'The user saved: ', savedUser )
             }).catch( (err) => {
                res.send( 'The user was not saved : ', err )
            })
        })
    } ).catch( err => {
        res.send( 'gen salt err :', err )
    })
})
```

I saw some similar question here but were not the same as this one.

Comment: Its because you are returning nothing from the function. .catch can be used on promises only

Comment: @GaneshKarewad tnx for the answer but I did so for the app.js, now POSTMAN does not respond and says: Loading ... I also replaced the inner then ... catch with try... catch but the result was same Loading loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.catch can be used on promise. as you are not returning any promise here(or anything at all), its like using .catch on undefined. Use try catch instead

```
app.post('/register', ( req, res ) => {
let newUser = new User()
newUser.email = req.body.email || 'gmail'
newUser.password = req.body.password || 1234
// res.send( newUser )
try{
  bcrypt.genSalt( 10,  salt => {
      bcrypt.hash( req.body.password, salt, ( err, hash ) => {
         if( err ) return err 
         newUser.password = hash
         newUser.save().then( savedUser => {
             res.send( 'The user saved: ', savedUser )
          }).catch( (err) => {
             res.send( 'The user was not saved : ', err )
         })
       })
  })
 } catch(err){
     res.send( 'gen salt err :', err )    
  }
})
```

Comment: I did so for the app.js, now POSTMAN  does not respond and says: `Loading ... 
` I also replaced the inner then ... catch with try... catch but the result was same Loading loop.

Comment: do not replace inner the.catch with try and catch as its a promise and it should be used the way it is written already

Comment: Tnx bro!  it works! 
I also replaced `res.send( 'The user saved: ', savedUser )` which is depricated
with `res.send(\`The user saved: ${userSaved}\`  )`